# How to link latitude and longitude with GeoNames?

Tags: geonames

I have a .csv file having following informations:
ID, Latitude, Longitude, Altitude, Date, Time

I want to link the Latitude and Longitude information with GeoNames Linked Data.

So, I have searched for following:

From the GeoNames data dump in text files I have downloaded the country data (IT.zip). And from the particular GeoID, I am able to do the following query on SPARQL endpoint.

```
select * from http://sws.geonames.org/2759794/about.rdf where { 
   ?s http://www.geonames.org/ontology#alternateName ?o; 
   wgs84_pos:long "38.23005565"; 
   wgs84_pos:lat "15.5511188825967".
}
```

But, the latitude and longitude information that I have in my .csv file is not present in the IT.zip (country) file.

I am able to retrieve location name form the Google API, but the names are not present in the IT.txt file.

I want to know can I able to connect my data into Linked GeoData?

Comment: sounds like your using a database as well with select statements?

Comment: Till now i have just checked the information is present or not in IT.zip file and GeoNames....

Answer (score 1):

Your SPARQL request cannot work properly, here is a corrected version :

```
PREFIX geo:<http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX cn:<http://www.geonames.org/ontology>

SELECT * FROM   
WHERE { 
   ?s cn:#alternateName ?o; 
      geo:long "38.23005565"; 
      geo:lat "15.5511188825967".
}
```

Moreover, your question has been answered here :

[Retrieving data from geonames using SPARQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393908/retrieving-data-from-geonames-using-sparql)